# Is there a cleaner way to write JS to show and hide?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hide, show

Hi I have a fiddle setup here that has 2 list items and when clicked they display by toggle a show/hide div - each with different content.

My worry is the way I have written the JS to control it. Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/b0xamuj8/

html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="revealerone">item 1</li>
    <li class="revealertwo">item 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="revealed one">this is some content one</div>
<div class="revealed two">this is some content two</div>
```

css:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: mome;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.revealed {
    display: none;
    background: green;
}
```

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".revealerone").click(function() {
            $(".one").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".revealertwo").click(function() {
            $(".two").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
```

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it.  There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scan past it to find the button) showing what your post would look like when posted. Please make use of them in future. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `data` attribute to determine which "revealer" goes with which "revealed":

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".revealer").click(function() {
        var id = "#" + $(this).data('item');
        $(id).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; }

li { display: inline-block; margin: 0 10px; }

.revealed { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="revealer" data-item="one">item 1</li>
    <li class="revealer" data-item="two">item 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="revealed" id="one">this is some content one</div>
<div class="revealed" id="two">this is some content two</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the target of the "revealer" in a data attribute and make your toggle code reusable like this:

HTML

```
<li class="revealer" data-target=".one">item 1</li>
<li class="revealer" data-target=".two">item 2</li>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".revealer").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $(target).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/b0xamuj8/2/

Answer (score 0):

In your case if HTML markup is consistent, you could use the index:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".revealer").click(function() {
        $(".revealed").eq($(this).index()).slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: mome;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

.revealed {
     display: none;   
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="revealer">item 1</li>
    <li class="revealer">item 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="revealed">this is some content one</div>
<div class="revealed">this is some content two</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li data-content-id="one" class="revealer">item 1</li>
 <li data-content-id="two" class="revealer">item 2</li>
</ul>

<div class="revealed one">this is some content one</div>
<div class="revealed two">this is some content two</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".revealer").click(function() {
    var contentId = $(this).data("content-id");
    $(".revealed." + contentId).slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```